# How to filter out results on the basis of odd and even row number using window functions, no existing column as Row ID

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am currently using the following code, but it is not working, Please guide me-

```
select name, Continent, LifeExpectancy
from world.country
where mod(Row_Number()
over(order by Continent),2)=0;
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data + results you are getting?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You typically would need a subquery here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Continent) rn
    FROM world.country
)

SELECT name, Continent, LifeExpectancy
FROM cte
WHERE rn % 2 = 0;  -- for evens
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a subquery to use the WINDOW funtion.
Can you pls try this ?

```
select name, Continent
from (
select name, Continent, LifeExpectancy, Row_Number() over(order by Continent) rn
from world.country) rs
where mod(rs.rn,2)=0;
```